# BigDecimal scale not working

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have the following code:

```
BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); //1
BigDecimal amountSum;

// amount sum computation

BigDecimal amountByCurrency = amountSum.divide(32); //-0.04
result.add(amountByCurrency); //2
```

After line `//1` scale is still 0. Why? So, the `//2` evaluation doesn't affect to the result. What's wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The important part of the [`#setScale` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) is this:

> Note that since BigDecimal objects are **immutable**, calls of this method do not result in the original object being modified, contrary to the usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X. Instead, setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the returned object may or may not be newly allocated.

*(emphasis added)*

Therefore, this line in your code won't change the `result` instance:

```
result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); //1
```

Either change it to:

```
result = result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
```

to overwrite the instance with the new one, or create a new variable and use that instead of `result`:

```
BigDecimal scaledResult = result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
```

Btw: the same applies to this line:

```
result.add(amountByCurrency); //2
```

You need to store the returned `BigDecimal` instance of the `#add` call in a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have changed the scale of `result`, but not the scale of `amountSum` or `amountByCurrency`, so when you operate with this variables you are working with scale 0.

If I remember well, there is a "global" method to set the default scale when you create a BigDecimal. You should use this method, or set the scale variable by variable.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is immutable, so nothing has changed at all.

Comment: scale is being recalculated on each BigDecimal instantiation (on each operation)