# bigdecimal and number of decimal

Tags: java

I try to do some caculation to get tax value. That work but it's display to much number.

```
 Price it's a BigDecimal     

 BigDecimal tps = price().multiply(tpsRate());
 tps.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

 BigDecimal tvq = price().multiply(tvqRate());
 tvq.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

 BigDecimal tps = report.getPrice().multiply(report.getTpsRate());
 tps.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

 BigDecimal tvq = report.getPrice().multiply(report.getTvqRate());
 tvq.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```

If the price is 200.00
tvq it's calculated to 14.0000
tps it's calculated to 18.0000

```
price().add(tvq).add(tps)
```

total 232.0000

I want to get 14.00, 18.00 and 232.00

Comment: I don't see any code that prints numbers. Add that code.

Comment: i use itext and i use toPlainString() to the bigdecimal to display it.

Comment: This might be a better dupe: [BigDecimal scale not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28216527)

Comment: @Tom Guessing that this is an XY problem. How to change the scale is the immediate problem, but the preferred way of formatting numbers doesn't need to change the scale, it uses a DecimalFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigDecimal, like String, are immutable.  This means you can't change the value, only return a new value.

```
tvq.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```

This calculates a BigDecimal with two decimal places, but you are discarding it.  I suspect you wanted to keep the value returned.

```
tvq = tvq.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```